# How to check an OS update is complete?

Tags: updates

Yesterday I was trying update my OS from 12.04 to 14.04.

This was done in my VirtualBox. I left the terminal open and continuing downloading during the night.

This morning when I came to my office, I saw the screen of my VirtualBox Ubuntu was deadlocked, I can't do any operation to it, it stays at some chromium interface I viewed last night.

So I forced restart it, and then I found I was enter into the interface of 14.04 . After I logged in, several error box popped out. But after I installed VirtualBox GuestAddtion package. No more error box popped out when I enter the GUI at the recently log-ins.

But I was still worried about if there may be some lethal bugs left when updating, at least it wasn't ended at an normal way.

So, is there a way that I can check if my update was complete?

Comment: Run sudo apt-get install -f command.it Wii fix the dependencies and broken packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it using `lsb_release -a`

```
user@Laptop~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

also check linux kernel version using `uname -r`

```
user@Laptop~$ uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

You can always `sudo apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f install` to meet dependencies and install/update apps

Comment: It's the same as you've mentioned above.

Comment: then you have **successfully upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**. Just perform `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`  to update and meet dependencies (just in case) and you are Good. If you are satisfied then please mark this as answered

Comment: correct returns from `lsb_release -a` and `uname -r` do **NOT** guarantee you  a successful or complete upgrade. Do run `sudo apt-get update, apt-get upgrade` to see more information.